# How to validate the restoration is successful

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have taken the full snapshot from a node. I have copied the snapshot directory and placed in the `/var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace/Tables/` directory in the restoration node. I have tried both restarting the service and also tried using `nodetool refresh` command for restoring the data in new node. It worked like a charm.

I am unable to list the number of records for tables with high number of records. I am facing **`Connection timed out`** error for tables with higher records. So I am unable to validate that the total data from the table has been successfully restored.

Also I tried check the size occupied by the keyspace using `nodetool cfstats -H` and `nodetool tablestats -H` and "Space used" parameter seems to be exactly matching.

I use below command for listing the total count of the specific tables.

```
select count(*) from milestone LIMIT 100000;
```

**My Question:**

What if few of the records went missing during restoration? What if the count from the backup and restored data has mismatched and I have no way of knowing it. Could you please suggest the way to validate that the restoration is successful?

How will I ensure the total number of records have successfully copied?

Comment: Count operations are pretty expensive. If you fell like you need to do it, cqlsh has a parameters that controls the request timeout. You can try it. --request-timeout="timeout" is the parameter. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually to validate data restoration, you may take a `CSV` backup of your data sets at the beginning and after restoration take one more `CSV` backup. Then compare these two backup, is there anything missing or not.

To compare to `csv`:

```
# diff mytable_old.csv mytable_new.csv
```

To know more about `CQLSH COPY` for `csv` backup: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your dataset size it might not be possible (reasonable?) to compare the full dataset.

Either using a random approach and query a % of the dataset.

If you do want to query the full dataset the best approach is to query all partitions one by one by token, and compare with the original dataset. You can look here https://github.com/ckalantzis/cassTickler for an example of how to query the full dataset. The objective is different, but the approach I'm recommending is the same.